# Minimum number of choices

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I haven't seen a question similar to this one asked yet, so I was wondering if anyone has any ideas.
Suppose ***x*** number of integers from 1 to 10 are chosen randomly (with possible repeats). The only information you know is the mean of these integers. Is it possible to find the smallest possible number ***x*** can be? If so, how?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Why ill-posed? One is given an average (mean) which is of course a rational number between $1$ and $10,$ and from that one asks for the fewest number of $x$ in a multi-set giving that mean.

Comment: @coffeemath You are right, I hadn't thought this through.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, x refers to the number of integers that were chosen. I did not assign a variable to the mean, which is assumed to be known.

Comment: I would say no, because choosing 3 numbers with a mean of 5 doesn't give you enough information to determine the lowest number. The 3 integers could be 4, 5, 6 or they could be 3, 5, 7. The lowest number cannot be determined with certainty here.

Comment: @JasonChen No no, I'm asking for x, which is the number of integers. In your example x would be 3 in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Let the mean $m$ be a rational in $[1,10]$ and write $m=\frac{p}q$ with $p$ and $q$ positive and coprime integers.

We must have $x\geq q$, for otherwise the denominator in the mean $m$ would be less than $q$. On the other hand, since $m$ lies in $[1,10]$, we have $q\leq p\leq 10q$, so $p$ may be written as the sum of $q$ integers between $1$ and $10$.

It follows that $x=q$ is the minimum possible value for $x$.